# How to call jquery function from @Html.ActionLink param routeValues

Tags: jquery, razor

I have a text box and a button upon clicking which should retrieve the value set in the text box and pass it to a controller. I am trying to do this by calling a JQuery function which returns me the value of text box and pass as routevalues parameter. I know this does not work, but my question is there a way to modify the below code to achieve this? Basically i want to know how can I plug getValue function inside ActionLink call.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {

    var getValue = function () {

        return $("#addtoset").val();
    };
});
</script>

@Html.TextBox("addtoset", "", htmlAttributes : new { @id = "addtoset", @class = "col-sm-10" })
@Html.ActionLink("Add To Set", "AddToSet", routeValues: new { amount = getValue()}, htmlAttributes : new { @id="linkSet", @class = "col-sm-2" })
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41084709/html-actionlinkmor-info-cityinfo-newcityid-getvalue-new-class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an onclick handler to the htmlattributes part of the ActionLink call like this:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Add To Set", "AddToSet", routeValues: new { amount = getValue()}, htmlAttributes : new { @id="linkSet", @class = "col-sm-2", onclick = "getValue" })
```

But if this is all your code you'll need to do more than that to get it to work :)

If you want the link to prevent navigation you add preventDefault() to your callbackFunction

```
function callbackFunc(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    // work here
}
```

Comment: So, does adding onclick attribute overrides default behavious of @Html.ActionLink() ? Basically what I need is to get the value from jquery function and pass it as routevalue to actionlink. Can you explain how above can achieve that?

Comment: Then i would add an onchange or onkeydown event to the input field, that would update the "Action" in your link. But why would you let users pick an action/controller? How do they know your model?

Comment: Users are not picking action/controller here. Just that I want to assign a value from a jquery function to amount field (amount = getValue()). If it is not possible, I will go down the usual way of wiring jquery functions to html links.

Comment: Why would an amount ever need to be in the url? Just post the value from the form .. don't use links for that!