# How To Send ActionLink Parameters With routevalue in asp.net mvc 5 to controller with jquery

Tags: jquery, razor, html.actionlink

```
@Html.ActionLink("mor info","CityInfo",new{cityid = --getvalue()--},new {@class = "mbtn" })
```

I want to get Value Selected In Dropdownlist CityId With Jquery
But I Can't Use JQuery Function in RouteValue

How to use JQuery Function in Routevalue?
or
How to Get selected CityId and Send To Action in Controller?

Comment: I think you didn't try to search out to achieve this. There are many possible methods to do this.

Comment: I Cant use Its solutions. can you help me? Thank you

Comment: I can Get CityId But I Cant Send to Controller. I need Sent Multiple Parameters. CityId One of several parameters

Comment: A piece of code makes a very bad title. Try describing your problem in that box.

Comment: thanks  Henk Holterman

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example You can achieve this with jQuery function on dropdown value change event and setting element href attribute.

If You want, change `<select />` to `@Html.DropDownListFor()` or `@Html.DropDownList()`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.myClass').change(function () {
            $('.mbtn').attr('href', '/MyController/CityInfo?cityid=' + $(this).val());
        });
    })
</script>

<select class="myClass">
    <option value="1">Texas</option>
    <option value="2">Sao Paulo</option>
    <option value="3">Mexico</option>
</select>

@Html.ActionLink("More Info", "CityInfo", null, new { @class = "mbtn" })
```

For more parameters You can for every dropdown set `class='myClass'` and different id. With it You should be able to use it as:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.myClass').change(function() {
            $('.mbtn').attr('href', '/MyController/CityInfo?cityid=' + $('#cityId').val() + '&userId=' + $('#userId').val());
        });
    })
</script>
```

Comment: really grateful